# ElasticSearch and Spark. When I lose one ES node of my cluster, it stop working

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark

I have a ElasticSearch cluster with 5 nodes and Spark Cluster. 
My index has 5 shards and 1 replica. It works fine until I lose one ES node, then it stops working.

Usually, I index about 30K/sec. When I lose one node I get 500/sec. I thought it could be because the shards are been replicated but I waited until all shards were okay and I have the same behavior. I tried to restart the 4 elasticsearch nodes which left, but it doesn't fix anything.

If I have a ES cluster with 3 nodes from the beginning it works fine as well. So, it's not a problem about performance and don't have enough nodes.

I'm using Spark 1.6, ES 2.2.0 and the library es-hadoop.

Comment: When a node goes down ES will rebalance the shards on that node. And if you have large data on your shards that can affect the performance.

Comment: I know, but after ES has rebalanced all shards, things don't get better.